# Как выполнить команды dos в windows 10 64

Tags: windows-10, bios, x86-64, dos

Я узнал что можно пользоваться Dosbox, но этот вариант мне не нравится, также знаю что можно загрузить msdos, но такой способ тоже не нравится. Вообщем мне надо сбросить bios, ибо он не разрешает работать в boot, я собираюсь в dos ввести соответсвующие команды для сброса (а именно debug.exe —> o702E o71FF q. Помогите как их ввести

Comment: Выполнить такое из-под другой операционной системы в принципе невозможно, загружайте msdos

Comment: Ну а вообще разве не достаточно просто вытащить батарейку для сброса? Ну или переключить какой-нибудь джампер согласно инструкции к материнке (если речь не о ноутбуке)